Mobx will not reorder the component to change the observable variable
Hey,
If I change the observabl variable using a function in the provider, the value of this.loaded in the sorter is changed to false, but the component that reads this value is not re-rendering.
Sorter


import { observable, action, makeObservable } from "mobx";

export class SorterSharedContextStore {
  private readonly sharedContext: SharedContextStore = new SharedContextStore();

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      loaded: observable,
      setLoaded: action
    });
  }

  loaded: string = "true";

  setLoaded() {
    console.log("setLoaded");
    this.loaded = "false";
  }

}



Provider


import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Provider, useLocalObservable } from 'mobx-react';
import sorterRootStore from 'stores/sorter-root-store';
import { dataGET } from 'wes_shell_app/api-utils';
import { SorterSharedContextStore } from 'stores/sorter-shared-context-store';
import { IAPIInductionStationModel } from 'models/server-models';

export const AppProvider = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
  
  const state = useLocalObservable(() => ({
    sharedContextStore: new SorterSharedContextStore(),
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const path = 'getInductionStations';
        const response: IAPIInductionStationModel = await dataGET(`?????????${path}`);
        state.sharedContextStore.setInductionStations(response);
        state.sharedContextStore.setLoaded();
        console.log(state.sharedContextStore.loaded);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider rootStore={sorterRootStore}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  );
};



My component


import { observer, useLocalObservable } from "mobx-react";
import { SimpleCard } from "wes_shell_app/simpleCard";
import BaseView from "wes_shell_app/base-view";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { SorterInductionStationViewStore } from "../stores/sorter-induction-station-view-store";
import { SorterInductionStationDataProvider } from "../stores/data/sorter-induction-station-data-provider";
import { SorterSharedContextStore } from "stores/sorter-shared-context-store";
import { IClientWaveInfoModel } from "models/client-models";
import { FormLabel } from "@mui/material";
import LocalizedText from "wes_shell_app/localized-text";

type InductionStationViewType = {
  id: number;
};

const IndustionStationView = observer(({ id }: InductionStationViewType) => {
  const provider = new SorterInductionStationDataProvider();
  const store = new SorterInductionStationViewStore();
  const waveInfo: IClientWaveInfoModel = store.waveInfo;

  const state = useLocalObservable(() => ({
    sharedContextStore: new SorterSharedContextStore(),
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    state.sharedContextStore.setActualInductionStationID(id);
    store.openConnection();
    return () => {
      store.closeConnection();
    };
  }, []);

  if (state.sharedContextStore.loaded === "true") return <div>Loading...{state.sharedContextStore.loaded}</div>;

  return (
    <BaseView cardBackgroundColor={false}>
      <div className="flex gap-5">
        <SimpleCard>
          <FormLabel className="text-xs" sx={{ fontSize: "0.75em" }}>
            <LocalizedText intlId="Info" />
          </FormLabel>
          <p className="text-2xl font-bold mt-3">FLOOR - On Floor Lab Sorter{waveInfo && waveInfo.sorter}</p>
          <p className="mt-2">ID: 3{waveInfo && waveInfo.sorterid}</p>
        </SimpleCard>
      </div>
    </BaseView>
  );
});

export default IndustionStationView;



My logging"
setLoaded sorter-shared-context-store.ts:56
false app-provider.tsx:21
It is clear from the log that the observable variable loaded is changed, but the component is not overwritten.
Does anyone know what could be causing this please?

Probably you have forgotten to bind your action.
As for me, the easiest way to avoid such problems is using the arrow function instead of simple function
try this
export class SorterSharedContextStore {
...
  setLoaded = () => {
    ...
  }
}

